# Linux - Cat command doesn't maintain the file format

Tags: linux, shell

I have a Linux script that generates an HTML file with various outputs for various Linux commands. 
Here is one of the outputs that creates an `intrf.txt`.  I generated this file using this command

```
ip link show|sed '=;G'>intrf.txt
```

I did that as I want the lines of file to have line space between.

If I do the `cat intrf.txt` command on my shell I can see indeed the line spacing. If I run the script with the function below I see all lines of this file on my browser, but concatenated with no space between.

Maybe this is something simple, but I cannot figure it out.

```
function net_ifconfig
{
  echo -e "GET http://google.com HTTP/1.0\n\n" | nc google.com 80 > /dev/null 2>&1
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "<h2 style="background-color:#00FF00"><font size="5"> CHECK 2.  LIST OF AVAILABLE INTERFACE</h2>"
    ip link show|sed '=;G'>intrf.txt
    cat intrf.txt
  else
    echo "CHECK 1. INTERNET IF OFFLINE"
    echo "<h2 style="background-color:#FF0000"><font size="5"> INTERNET IS NOT CONNECTED</h2>"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Your browser is displayuing the text as HTML but HTML ignores whitespace and requires <br> and <p> tags to indicate spacing.

Comment: Thank you. This made me search more the tags. seems pre tag works great.

Comment: I should have thought of that...

Answer (score 0):

Seems if I put the command between pre tags it works.

```
echo "<pre>"
ip link show|sed '=;G'>intrf.txt
cat intrf.txt
echo "</pre>"
```